# Partial full link Framework in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a xcode project which depends on several prebuilt frameworks, for example a.Framework and b.Framework.

What I want to do is to link the symbols in a.Framework only if they `are referred`, and link `all the symbols` in b.Framework. Just like what `LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES` and `LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES` does in Android make file.

I know the `-ObjC` in the `other link flags` could result a full link but I don't want. Because that would make a.Framework be full link too.

So any way to make xcode only full link part of the Frameworks?

Comment: You must know if the symbols are referenced or not and why would that change?

Comment: Because the frameworks were provided by different third parties. Only one of the frameworks need to be full linked and I don't add the -ObjC because it would cause all the other frameworks to be full linked too, which is unnecessary.